# Lua Can anyone explain what this does?

Tags: lua

I'm learning lua, can anyone explain how this small bit of code works?

```
table = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

function num(table, start)
  table = start

  return function()
    i = i + 1
    if table[i - 1] then
      return i - 1,[table - 1]
    else
      return nil
  end
end

for k,v in ipairs(table) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

Comment: `return i - 1,[table - 1]` is syntax error. Where did you see this script?

Comment: it also lacks `end` for `else` statement

Comment: The code looks really bad. `num` isn't used anywhere in it; the `table` parameter to it is immediately assigned over, making it pointless; `i` is a global and not defined anywhere, so `i = i+1` will fail; and as hjpotter and lukas point out, it's ill formed.

Comment: This code will give you output of `1,1` `2,2`, `3,3`, `4,4`, `5,5`. `num` function will never be called. And if it will - it produce error: not enough `end` statements. Or earlier - `[t-1]` is something not from Lua. Well, it just mysterious chunk =)

Comment: It looks like num was going to be an iterator. My guess is this isn't all of the code

Comment: Did an answer here help you? Don't forget to mark it as best answer with that green checkmark next to it! If not, perhaps you should add more details to your original question, in order to receive better help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that code was leading up to a custom iterator function. But it isn't finished, here's my best guess at what it should look like

```
tab = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

function num(tab, start)
  local i = start or 1
  return function()
    i = i + 1
    if tab[i - 1] then
      return i - 1,tab[i - 1]
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end

for k,v in ipairs(tab) do
  print(k,v)
end

for k,v in num(tab) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

What this code would do is first loop through tab and print the key value pairs. Next it uses an iterator that it made which prints the key value pairs before it.

The iterator continues to return until it returns nil. Then the for loop ends.